# Mysql syntax seems correct

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-error

So... I received:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = '48f9f4a3f5e10c63804400f320f46e26'' at line 1
```

and so I reflected it back to myself, on the webpage and it reads:

```
SELECT * FROM email_confirm WHERE email = 'censored@gmail.com' AND key = '48f9f4a3f5e10c63804400f320f46e26'
```

I don't see the issue.

MySQL version is 5.1.65-cll

Answer:
    KEY is a reserved word in mysql. Need `backticks` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` is a MySQL keyword. Since it's also the name of your field, enclose it with the appropriate symbols:

```
SELECT * FROM `email_confirm` WHERE `email` = 'censored@gmail.com' AND `key` = '48f9f4a3f5e10c63804400f320f46e26';
```

Comment: Gotta love it when two people answer 15 seconds apart!

Comment: I feel like I should have thought about that more. I thought it, but ignored the thought (and forgot about it). Thank you Anton!

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to choose an answer, it helps our reps :)

Comment: Had to wait the default 10 mins! Get me some rep too. I'm new to stackoverflow! (Greatly Appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

Key is a reserved word.  Use backticks to escape it.

```
... `key` = '48f9...'
```

Comment: And Thank you. Anton appeared first on the page :-\ haha

Answer (score 1):

I think key is a reserved word. Use `key` instead.